# Retrofit with soap api

Tags: soap, retrofit

I am trying to create Retrofit instance with the soap API. But I don't have an idea how to create. I have checked all the websites. I have got the code for creating the Retrofit instance with Rest API.

Also, I am having WSDL file. I am able to create required POJO class with that but I don't know how to use for a service call.

Kindly anyone please suggest some code or how to use that.

For Rest call, I am creating Retrofit instance like

```
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<User>> listUsers(@Path("user") String user);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should first make `ApiClient` class as follow:

```java
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://54.255.249.65/socialcommerce/rest/V1/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

In the controller class you should use the above class as follow:

```java
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClientInstagram.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<InstagramDetail> call = apiInterface.getInstagramDetail(token);
Log.d("tag", call.request().url().toString());

call.enqueue(new Callback<InstagramDetail>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<InstagramDetail> call, Response<InstagramDetail> response) {
        String code = String.valueOf(response.code());
        if (code.equals("200")) {
            response.body();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backend Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<InstagramDetail> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: The question is about SOAP call through Retrofit, not REST.